# apk installed package not available in container

Tags: linux, docker, alpine-linux

I'm building an image using alpine linux as follows:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk update \
apk upgrade \
apk add bash

CMD ["sh","ls"]
```

I'm expecting bash to be available in the container but when I run it it can't find bash

```
docker run -it --rm tmp:latest /bin/sh
/ # bash
/bin/sh: bash: not found
```

If anybody can help me understand why it's not available it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `&&` after each apk command, like the Dockerfile below. When docker builds your container, your original `RUN` line expanded to the single command `apk update apk upgrade apk add bash` instead of separate commands. So the `apk add bash` command wasn't properly run when you built the image.

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk update \
 && apk upgrade \
 && apk add bash

CMD ["sh","ls"]
```

You should combine separate commands with `&&` so if one fails, this will be reported when building the image.